Wrapping minted-Enviroment in a ocg-Enviroment
I cannot wrap my minted-Environment, which is wrapped in a tcolorbox into an ocg-Environment.
The wrapping of the minted-Environment into the tcolorbox is working fine.
Does anyone more competent than me knows a solution?
Minimal Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{ocgx2}


%%Ein- und Ausblendbare tcolorbox - mittels \tcblower vertikal:
\newtcolorbox{antwortside}[0]{
    colframe = blue!90!white,
    colback = green!90!white,
    coltext = black,
    %sharp corners,
    sidebyside = true,
    bicolor,
    colbacklower=blue!50!white,
    boxsep=7pt,
    left=5pt,
    %right=5pt,
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    enlarge left by=15mm,  % Vergrößert den Abstand zum linken Rand
    enlarge right by=20mm,  % Vergrößert den Abstand zum rechten Rand
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,
    after=\par\medskip
}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newcommand{\sideantwort}[2]{
    \noindent\switchocg{#1}{\fbox{Antwort}}
    \begin{ocg}{test}{#1}{0}
        \begin{antwortside}
            #2
        \end{antwortside}
    \end{ocg}
    %\noindent
}

%Python-Umgebung:
\newenvironment{pythoncode}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
   \begin{minted}[breaklines,autogobble]{python}}
  {\end{minted}}

\begin{document}
Testtext beginnt eben genau hier\sideantwort{col2}{
\begin{pythoncode}
import numpy as np
    def incmatrix(genl1, genl2):
        m = len(genl1)
        n = len(genl2)
\end{pythoncode}
    \tcblower
    Das ist Python-code mit Syntax Highlighting
}
\end{document}

Error:
C:\Users\Tristan\Desktop\Arbeit\Schule\Latex-Vorlagen\Arbeitsblatt>set  /p x= 0<nul: 1>>minimal.aex
system returned with code 1

(./minimal.aux) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii

[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
! Argument of \FV@BeginScanning has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.53 }

?
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.53 }


I think that {pythoncode} contains verbatim material, and it's not possible to put verbatim material in the argument of a command (\sideantwort). It's possible to put verbatim material within the body of an environment...

The environment {pythoncode} contains verbatim material, and it's not possible to put verbatim material in the argument of a command. It's possible to put verbatim material within the body of an environment. Thus, I suggest replacing your command sideantwort by an environment {sideantwort}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage{ocgx2}


%%Ein- und Ausblendbare tcolorbox - mittels \tcblower vertikal:
\newtcolorbox{antwortside}[0]{
    colframe = blue!90!white,
    colback = green!90!white,
    coltext = black,
    %sharp corners,
    sidebyside = true,
    bicolor,
    colbacklower=blue!50!white,
    boxsep=7pt,
    left=5pt,
    %right=5pt,
    width=0.9\textwidth,
    enlarge left by=15mm,  % Vergrößert den Abstand zum linken Rand
    enlarge right by=20mm,  % Vergrößert den Abstand zum rechten Rand
    before=\par\medskip\noindent,
    after=\par\medskip
}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\newenvironment{sideantwort}[1]{
    \noindent\switchocg{#1}{\fbox{Antwort}}
    \begin{ocg}{test}{#1}{0}
        \begin{antwortside}}
    {\end{antwortside}
    \end{ocg}}

%Python-Umgebung:
\newenvironment{pythoncode}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
   \begin{minted}[breaklines,autogobble]{python}}
  {\end{minted}}

\begin{document}

Testtext beginnt eben genau hier
\begin{sideantwort}{col2}
\begin{pythoncode}
import numpy as np
    def incmatrix(genl1, genl2):
        m = len(genl1)
        n = len(genl2)
\end{pythoncode}
    \tcblower
    Das ist Python-code mit Syntax Highlighting
\end{sideantwort}
\end{document}



Suggestion: Take a look at the package piton.  It's as powerful as minted for the formatting of Python listings and does not require external program.
